# Only Keeping a single frame of Smoke Simulation

Tags: baking, smoke-simulation, cache

I have a smoke simulation that I want to render and the frame I want to render is around the middle of the whole sequence. Since I'm going to upload this on a render farm, I must keep the cache size minimal. But the whole bake takes about 4GB of space. Is there a way to bake the whole simulation (because otherwise it doesn't work) and then keep only a few frames of cache?

Comment: New user here but I think you just need to find the simulation files (look for dir with prefix like "blendcache") and upload only those named with the frame number you want to render. For example, `43756265_000034_00.bphys` is for frame 34. (I know this same idea works for fluid simulations...I thought it worked for smoke as well...but given the lack of answers here maybe I'm out of my depth.)